# Bridging router without a bridge mode

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, nat

My ISP-supplied router is very buggy and has various issues with port forwarding and NAT loopback which they can't fix (even after sending a replacement, it had the exact same issue), so I've decided to buy a new, higher quality router.

Other people in my house want the ISP-supplied router to stay working (as it has backup 4G data and works fine for basic use) so I thought I would bridge this router to the new one I'm buying, with the new one being used as the primary one:

[image]

However, my ISP router does not have a bridge mode. I can manually disabled DHCP and NAT, but I want to be absolutely sure before I buy another router:

Can I successfully bridge my ISP router without any issues just by disabling DHCP on it? Will any devices connected to this secondary router still be issued an IP properly from the primary router?

I also want to make sure that different devices connected to each router can still properly communicate with each other properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I successfully bridge my ISP router without any issues just by
> disabling DHCP on it?

No.  Bridging the ISP Modem means your Router will pick up the External IP for network.

The ISP must support bridging for you to implement bridging. If they support it, they will usually set it up for you.

You can attach your own router, use a different subnet and set up DHCP on it. But that is not the same as bridging.

Comment: Glad I checked, thanks.